# Task with multiple stored procedures

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to create a task within snowflake to call multiple stored procedures?

For example I have three stored procedures to check for duplicated information over multiple tables, I'd like to call all three through the task without having to create a new SP to loop through them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A task can only trigger one SQL statement or one Stored Procedure.

So you have to decide:

1. One task for each procedure with dependencies between the tasks
2. One task with a wrapper procedure that calls all the three Stored Procedures (the solution you do not want to have)

I think chaining the tasks is a good solution. You have to use the AFTER-clause within your CREATE TASK-statement to achieve the correct dependencies: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html

Comment: Hello team, I know I'm late to the discussion BUT could I not have how towards the end of snowflake doc in above URL suggests. Have a different sql_delimiter and wrap multiple proc calls within BEGIN AND END statements ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. This was not possible back then.

Comment: OKAY thank you so much. Am working on this now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A task can only call 1 SP so if you don't want to write one SP that calls the others then how about creating a chain of 3 tasks?